# What strategies should I use as a fighter?

Tags: desktop-dungeons-2010

[image: Any help on beating this dungeon?]

I am have difficulty beating dungeons with the Fighter. Any tips for this dungeon and future ones?

Comment: Is there any specific problem you're having?  Like there's a monster that trips you up, or you can't open a chest, or something?  Right now, this is too general to be properly answered.

Comment: @fbueckert I edited the title, I think what he's getting at is he needs tips for how to take advantage of a Fighter's special abilities, which seems sufficiently narrow.

Comment: @bwarner Hmm.  I had read that as broader than you did.  Your interpretation is definitely narrow enough, I think.

Comment: Although this isn't a good answer, have you checked the [Fighter Strategy section on the wiki](http://www.qcfdesign.com/wiki/DesktopDungeons/index.php?title=Alpha:Fighter)?